# NodeJS and Mocha :Test is getting passed, instead of getting failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, mocha.js, chai

Below program is to read all the files under a folder and check if all the files contains email information.

The below test should be failed(i.e.., promise to be rejected and status should be failed) when the condition in the second "if" statement is true. Execution is getting stopped, but the test is getting passed instead of getting failed.
So, How do i make the below test fail.

Thanks in Advance.

```
var checkFileContent = function(directory) {
  var results = [];
  fs.readdir(directory, function(err, list) {
   // if (err) return done(err);
   console.log("The folder or list of file names :  " + list);
var i = 0;
(function next() 
{
  var file = list[i++];
 // if (!file) return done(null, results);
  file = directory + '/' + file;
  fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) 
  {
    if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) 
    {
      checkFileContent(file, function(err, res) 
      {
        results = results.concat(res);
        next();
      });
    } else

    {
      fs.readFile(file, "utf8", function(err, data) 
        {
           // if ( err )
          //  { throw err;}
           console.log(file +" file content is");
           console.log(data);
           console.log( data.toLowerCase().indexOf('email'));

           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if(data.toLowerCase().indexOf('email') != -1)
            {
                return reject(file + 'contains email ');
            }
            else

    {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
      {
      fs.readFile(file, "utf8", function(err, data) 
        {
           // if ( err )
          //  { throw err;}
           console.log(file +" file content is");
           console.log(data);
           console.log( data.toLowerCase().indexOf('email'));

          //return newfunc(file,data);

              if(data.toLowerCase().indexOf('email') != -1)
              {
                reject(file + 'contains email ');

               }
              else
              {
                  console.log(file + 'doesnt contain email');
                  resolve(true);
              }
          }).catch ((err) =>
            {
               //Execution is getting stopped here, but the test is getting passed instead of getting failed.
                return reject(err);
          });

        });

        results.push(file);
          //console.log("List of files under the current Log folder are : " + results);
        next();
      } // else closure
  }); // fs.stat() closure

})();  });
```

}

The above function is being called from another JS File using Mocha as shown below :

```
  it('should read Log files', function () {
    return ----
        .then((abc) => {
            ------
        }).then(()=>
        {
             return JSFileName.checkFileContent(directory);

        }).catch((err) => {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        })
})
```

Comment: Ultimately, `checkFileContent` should (at the top level of that function) return a promise. As-is, there's a promise being returned in some nested callback, which is "too late". But besides that, perhaps you should consider using a module like [`walk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/walk) or [`filehound`](https://github.com/nspragg/filehound).

Comment: It is too complicated code due to so many nested promises so best would be to use an *async* test and await the checkFileContent method's promise so that wherever in the promise chain the reject may happen, your test will be able to catch it.

Comment: @rjv : Thanks for your comment. Can you please write the code in brief,so that i can get an idea of how can that be done.

Comment: @navyashree - as mentioned in the two comments, your code is complicated and only you can refactor it.

However, coincidentally (and this is not for self-promotion so please others excuse the hint at it), I recently blogged on promises. Please refer to this link - https://ravichandranjv.blogspot.in/ - for some helpful code on promise rejection handling.

Comment: @rjv : Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @user2347763 self promotion is fine.  However given the nature of blogs, it would be best to link to the specific blog post (or tag) that you are referring to.  You have 11 years of blog posts!

Comment: Thanks for visiting my blog! Here is the link to Promises -https://ravichandranjv.blogspot.com/2018/03/the-unhandled-promise-rejection-state.html?m=1